# Getting Errors when running this code using Twilio API

Tags: flutter, dart, http, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to use the twilio api in flutter for whatsapp notifications but when running this code the whole application crashes and gives me errors and I dont have any idea why it is happening. *removed the twilioAccountSid and twilioAuthToken and used a fake number for security that is not the issue.

```
Future<void> sendWhatsAppMessage(
    String recipientWhatsAppNumber, String message) async {
  const twilioAccountSid = '';
  const twilioAuthToken = '';
  const twilioNumber = '+11234567890';

  final basicAuth =
      'Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode('$twilioAccountSid:$twilioAuthToken'))}';

  final Uri uri = Uri.parse(
      'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$twilioAccountSid/Messages.json');

  final Map<String, String> body = {
    'To': 'whatsapp:$recipientWhatsAppNumber',
    'From': twilioNumber,
    'Body': message,
  };

  final response = await http.post(
    uri,
    headers: <String, String>{
      'authorization': basicAuth,
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: body,
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('WhatsApp message sent successfully.');
  } else {
    print(
        'Failed to send WhatsApp message. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}
```

I tried to fix it using a different import and that gave me the same outcome of crashing and giving me call stack errors
the call stack error-
_NativeSocket.lookup. (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:520)
 (Unknown Source:0)
_NativeSocket.staggeredLookup..lookupAddresses. (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:0)
 (Unknown Source:0)

Comment: Can you update the question with the errors?